# How to ensure Linked CA Trust Chain / Should or Can I install Intermediate CA on Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have a [major corporate] client who are about to change the SSL certificates that they use with their API services.

I have an application with APIs that consume those of our client (server to server, not browser to server).

Our client has issued a Linked CA certificate to 3rd parties (such as my company).   We have been instructed to install the supplied certificate onto our servers.

I have been tasked to prove that our own service will continue to work after their change.  I believe that I may need to be able to demonstrate the chain of trust.

The supplied Linked CA is "DigiCert Global CA G2".

Our own APIs are hosted on an Azure API/WebApp.

I do not believe that we should even be considering installing Linked CA's on Azure app services.    I suspect that MS manage this entirely as part of the platform.

I have raised this question as a helpdesk ticket with Azure support, but after a few false-starts explaining the issue, the advise we have now received is a reference to this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-client-certificate-authentication-for-an-azure-web-app/.   With genuine respect to MS helpdesk, I don't believe that this addresses my issue.

To clarify, I am explicitly not talking about installing an SSL certificate on our own systems.

Our client has not yet started using their replacement SSL certs ... so I'm unclear how I might go about positively proving that the replacement SSL certs will work, without having visibility of them in advance.

To distill my question into two parts:

"is what I've been tasked to do even possible without visibility of the subject SSL?".

"should I be contemplating installing a Linked CA onto an Azure App service?  (and if so, how)".

Comment: Are you sure that's a root cert? The transparency log at crt.sh knows only one cert for that name, and it's an intermediate. Which is under a root C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert Global Root G2 which is reported as trusted by MS, and thus I presume by Azure.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thankyou, this is a good callout.  I am dealing with an intermediate cert (the client has identified it as a "linked CA certificate" - I will update the original post to reflect this.  In hindsight, it makes no sense that it would have been a root.